# call js function when new tab is opened in firefox

Tags: firefox-addon

I am working in firefox add ons. Let's have a simple code like this:

overlay.xul

```
 <script src="overlay.js"/> 

 <menupopup id="menu_ToolsPopup"> 
    <menuitem id="helloworld-hello" label="&helloworld;" 
    oncommand="Helloworld.onMenuItemCommand(event);"/> 
 </menupopup>
```

And overlay.js

```
var Helloworld = {
  onLoad: function() {
    // initialization code
    this.initialized = true;
  },

  onMenuItemCommand: function() {
    alert("JAVASCRIPT");
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) { Helloworld.onLoad(e); }, false);
```

It creates one tool on menu bar and if I clicked alert message will be displayed. It is working perfect. But my need is, alert message will be displayed when new tab is opened and browsed a url in firefox.

That means "onMenuItemCommand" function will be called when new tab is opened and browsed a url in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There is event listener for `TabOpen`. You may also be interested in when a window opens. I'm not sure if in a brand new window, if the `TabOpen` even triggers for that initial tab, if you can find out please share.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/TabOpen

You would attach this event to the `tabbrowser` element. For example:

```
Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gBrowser.addEventListener('TabOpen', function() {
    Services.prompt.alert(null, 'opened tab', 'hi');
}, false);
```

Comment: Actually my query is, need to call a js function from xml file when new tab is opened, so I need the xml code.

Comment: @KrishKowsi I don't get your question.

Comment: Actually my problem is, I can't able to call js file directly, I can call js function through xml file. In my existing code I called js function by clicking on the menu but now I need to call the same function without clicking the menu. That is once browser opens or new tab open the js function will be automatically trigger. And those js function calling code will be given in xml.